# Can i tell winscp to make a sound when it disconnects?

Tags: windows, winscp

Sometimes i am working on a text file and after i save it and check other things i come back and see its wrong or think my changes went through when it has not. Its really annoying especially when it seems random

Is there a way i can tell winscp to make a sound so i know when it didnt upload the change, needs me to answer the promp or whatever else that prevent it from uploading that second?

Answer (score 1):

You can have WinSCP show a balloon notification. See [link](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_environment) (bottom of the image).
It should also flash in the taskbar if you minimize it.

More sounds have been [suggested in the forums](http://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9508) and may be on it's way.